# Function that takes a number as an argument and returns a boolean javascript

Tags: javascript, function, return, boolean

I am new to coding and I have this exercise where I have to write a function that takes a number as argument and returns a boolean. This is the code I wrote but is not working and I am getting the warning

> "The function should only have a return statement in its body. You can evaluate a boolean expression an return immediately its value"

```js
var even = function(x) {
  if ((x % 2) === 0) {
    return true;
  } else
    return false;
};
```

Comment: The expression `x % 2 === 0` will already return `true` and `false`. Your function can just return that immediately `return x % 2 === 0` instead of writing `true` and `false` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response you get from the code submission has an important point:

The expression `(x%2)===0` is *already* a boolean, so you can return *that* expression:

```
return x%2 === 0;
```

In general you should avoid this pattern:

```
if (some_boolean_expression) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

... since the boolean you return is exactly the same as the boolean expression that is evaluated in the `if` condition. So it should be just:

```
return some_boolean_expression;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! These have been my first days coding and I've been using an school platform that gives hints on where to look for errors. How can I test the code in a real platform? Is it a program I should download or is thera some in-built application on windows? Thank you

Comment: Several options: you can create a text file with .htm extension, add some basic HTML, like `<html><body><script> ....your javascript ....</script></body></html>`, and then load that page in a browser. To quickly output a value, add `console.log(my_value)` in your JavaScript code, and press F12 in the browser to see the output. Alternatively, you can press F12 now (on any page), and start typing, and see the immediate result. But that is only practical for small pieces of code.

Answer (score 0):

you can just write your function like this

```
var even = function(x)
{
   return x % 2 === 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var even = function(x) {
    if (typeof x === "number") {
        if (x % 2 === 0) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    } else {
        return false

    }
}
```

This covers all the edge cases